# I have binary serialization/json in c# , how can i achive this in sqlserver

Tags: c#, sql-server

people said clr,

please tel me which way will be good to serialize .

I have to select a set of rows and seiralise it into a serialized object and insert it into a table into a image or new data types like varbinary , varchar nvarchar max etc

yours sincerley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL 2016 there is a huge support for json.

You can see Microsoft specification at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921897.aspx#Import JSON data into SQL Server tables